# Finding method of moment estimator from exponentially distributed random sample.

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

Given a random sample $X_1,...,X_n$ that are $IID$ from an exponential population with a unknown parameter $\lambda>0$

The parameter of interest is $\theta=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\lambda}$

Im looking to find the method of moments estimator for $\theta$.

Without giving the answer out right could you please tell me if im on the right track
$$\begin{aligned} E(X) &= \frac{1}{\lambda}\\ &=\bar{x}\end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned} \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\lambda} &= \theta \\ \sqrt{\lambda} &=2\theta \\ \lambda &= 4\theta^2\end{aligned}$$

And from here do i need to work out the mean of the sample of exponential random variables and which may perhaps use the properties of the gamma distribution? or do i just equate the mean of the sample $\bar{x}= E(X) = \frac{1}{\lambda}$ and then solve for the parameter of interest ($\theta$)?

Any pointers as to whether I'm on the right path at all much appreciated!

Comment: You should separate parameter and random variable terms.  In other words, you have the mean of the $X_i$ being $\mu=1/\lambda$.  Now by the method of moments substitute the sample mean for the population mean and replace $\lambda$ by its estimator:  $\bar{x}=1/\hat{\lambda}$.  Then $\hat{\lambda}=1/\bar{x}$ and $\hat{\theta}=\sqrt{\hat{\lambda}}/2=1/(2\sqrt{\bar{x}})$.

Comment: But, just FYI, $E(1/\bar X) \ne \lambda.$ Method-of-moments estimators derived using nonlinear operations are not necessarily unbiased. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Parameter_estimation).

Comment: @JimB thanks I eventually worked out the same solution but it's nice to get confirmation I did the right thing.

Comment: @BruceET thank you for that tip. A little bit sloppy on my behalf. I have a lot to learn!